# jQuery Datatables Search only one column

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables and ColdFusion. I am trying to have search field that will search only the first column (ITEM ID) so when you start typing into ITEM ID it will only search the table for the ITEM ID section and not all columns since due_date and QTY will also have similar numbers.

jQuery

```
var oTable = $('#processing').DataTable( {
$('#ItemID').on( 'keyup', function () {
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
    });
```

HTML - CF

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
     <label for="ItemID">ITEM ID</label>
         <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemID" id="ItemID" maxlength="15"> <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Search">SEARCH</button>
        </span>

         </div>
</div>

    <table id="processing" class="table table-hover">
             <thead>
                    <th><b>ITEM ID</b></th>
                    <th><b>DUE DATE</b></th>
                    <th><b>STATUS</b></th>
                    <th><b>QTY</b></th>
            </thead>
  <tbody>
    <cfoutput query="processTable">
       <cfif #Date_Complete# EQ "">
        <tr>
           <td class="LAlign">#id#</td>
           <td>#dateFormat(processTable.Date_Due, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
           <td>PROCESSING</td>
           <td>#Item_Count#</td>
        </tr>
     </cfif>
   </cfoutput>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

cfc

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var processTable = ''>
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT id, Date_Due, Date_Complete, Item_Count
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

What I tried (along with many other combinations):

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSearchable": true},
            { "bSearchable": false},
            { "bSearchable": false},
            { "bSearchable": false}
        ],
```

So basically I just want to search only the ID column. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use external search control and [`column().search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29) API method.

```
$('#ItemID').on('keyup change', function () {
   oTable.column(0).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

However, it would be much simple to instruct DataTables to make all columns except the first one not searchable with [`columnDefs.searchable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable) option and utilize internal search control.

```
var oTable = $('#processing').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "targets": [1,2,3], "searchable": false }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Any way to reset this filter?

Comment: Really easy oTable.column(0).search('').draw();